# Getting 'might not have been initialized' error

Tags: java, loops, if-statement

This is the error message. It's not brackets or the semicolon. I stated it in the beginning of my code I don't understand why it isn't working.

```
digits.java:25: error: variable countZ might not have been initialized
           countZ++;
           ^
digits.java:33: error: variable countO might not have been initialized
           countO++;
```

My code

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class digits
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {

    int len,number2,x;
    String number = new String();
    int countZ,countO,countE = 0;
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a number: ");
    number = read.nextLine();
    len = number.length();
    System.out.println(number);
    System.out.println(len);


    for(int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        number2 = Integer.parseInt(number.substring(i,i+1));

        if (number2 == 0)
        {
           countZ++;
        }
        else if (number2 % 2 == 0)
        {
           countE++;
        }
        else
        {
           countO++;
        }   
    }


    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think this line `int countZ,countO,countE = 0;` does?

Answer (score 1):

You issue is when you used to declare multiple variables and initialize there values at once.

try this :

```
   int countZ = 0,countO = 0,countE = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

What do you think this line int countZ,countO,countE = 0 --> By this you are initializing only the last, and you are expected to initialize the instance variables befor using them.

Initialize the countZ, count0 also.

Answer (score 0):

```
int countZ,countO,countE = 0;
```

->

```
int countZ = 0;

int countO = 0;

int countE = 0;
```

Then it will work.